# Highlight cell based on whether or not a specific word appears in a given range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, formatting, find

I have 2 sheets. **Sheet1** & **Sheet2**.

**Sheet 1** has a list of items with descriptions & specific numbers.
**Sheet 2** has a table filled with the same items.

What I am wanting to do, is highlight a selected cell in **Sheet2** if a specific word is mentioned ANYWHERE in **Sheet1** using conditional formatting.

For example, if my **Sheet2** is a table of numbers 1-12 (Jan-Dec)
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11 12

And I have a list of dates in Sheet1 column C ex.

January 1, 20xx
February 10, 20xx
January 20, 20xx
December 18, 20xx
July 10, 20xx
March 5, 20xx
September 9, 20xx

In **Sheet2**, I want the "**1**" cell highlighted if the word "**January**" is found ANYWHERE in **Sheet1** (specifically in **column C**, but if there is a command for the whole sheet that would be useful as well). As long as it appears ONCE, I want the cell with "**1**" highlighted. And so on.

I have gotten a formula to where I can highlight the cell "**1"** in **Sheet2** if I point it to only ONE cell

**=SEARCH("January",Sheet2!C5)**

but I can't figure out how to make it search the entire page, a certain range, or even just that column. I have tried adjusting the C5 to C5:C13, C:C, A1:C9, $C$5, and so many other combinations. I just want it to comb a specific range and highlight my cell as long as the word is found even once.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this as **New Rule** to format selected range in Sheet 2:

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D$15,Sheet1!$C:$C,1,FALSE)))
```

**Note,**

- To make the Search Dynamic in Cell `D15`write `January`.
- This formula will search `January` in 
  entire `C column` of `Sheet 1` & Format 
  the Selected  Data range in 
  `Sheet 2`since it returns `TRUE`.

*Adjust the cell references in formula as needed.*

Comment: The formula *kind of* worked. I change the "D$15" to **January** right? So my column C in Sheet1 has more words than just the dates. Some of them may say "Between January 1 & January 10." I played with the formula to make sure it worked, and it looks like it may only be reading the first word of each cell in the column? If I change the word January to another month, it still works. But when I change it to let's say just the number **10** I do not get the conditional formatting I am looking for, as if it doesn't find the 10 in a string of text containing it even though it is in column C.

Comment: @John, if column C has Date rather than Text January then you need to apply MMMM format to the Column C then Excel will convert those dates to respective months and this Formula will read the January for conditional formating.

Comment: ,,,Cont. if then you find any issue then better share the Sample data with us will help us to fix it. ☺